# AS3: change handcursor graphic on buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseover

I would like to replace the little handcursor that appears when hovering over movieclips with buttonMode=true by a custom graphic.

Is there any way to do this globally for my whole application or do I have to go to every single button, add MOUSE_OVER, MOUSE_OUT and MOUSE_MOVE handlers which will hide and show the mouse cursor as well place the handgraphics over it and position it correctly?

seems tedious...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could write a single set of MOUSE_OVER, MOUSE_MOVE and MOUSE_OUT handlers that do the replacement and positioning as you described but then add listeners to all your buttons that point to these handlers. Remember, the same handlers can be used for multiple objects.

Or alternatively, assuming your 'buttons' are MovieClips, you could write a custom  ActionScript class that extends MovieClip, defines this default functionality and then have all your button instances use this class as a base. See below:

```
    public class ButtonMovieClip extends MovieClip {

        public function ButtonMovieClip() {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, buttonOver);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, buttonOut);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, buttonMove);
        }

        public function buttonOver(event:MouseEvent) {
            //Hide mouse and add replacement graphic
        }

        public function buttonOut(event:MouseEvent) {
            //Show mouse and remove graphic
        }

        public function buttonMove(event:MouseEvent) {
            //Position graphic where mouse should be
        }
    }
```

The key then is to ensure all your buttons are created from this class (either by code or from within the Flash IDE).

Comment: I like your BaseClass idea - that will do the trick :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a way to change the native cursor; http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Mouse.html#registerCursor()

But you would have to target flash player 10.2+ only...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, **registerCursor** doesn't allow you to specify different cursors for different states so you'd still have to add MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT listeners for every object and call **registerCursor** and **unregisterCursor** instead. Granted, you wouldn't need the MOUSE_MOVE handler anymore.

Comment: I only have CS5, so I could not test it. But registerCursor takes a name for the cursor, so if you send it "MouseCursor.HAND", it should "replace" the hand cursor "system wide". Again, I have not tested it but this is how I would interpet the documentation.

Comment: I can confirm this works. You can use `Mouse.registerCursor(MouseCursor.BUTTON, cursorData)` to change the buttonMode=true hand cursor through your whole application in 10.2+.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong - it does NOT work. Mouse.cursor is always set to MouseCursor.AUTO whether it looks like an arrow or a hand. Overriding BUTTON or HAND does nothing unless your code explicitly sets Mouse.cursor to them. You can use registerCursor to override AUTO, but it will be static unless you can modify MouseCursorData to act the way AUTO does.